# Samba can't fetch domain SID after joining AD domain

Tags: samba, sssd, winbind

This is my scenario:

I have a CentOS 7.5 server which must act as a file server and allow AD-integrated authentication for Samba access, without the need to create local users with `smbpasswd`.
Samba Version 4.7.1
SSSD Version 1.16.0

What I've done so far:

Joined my linux server to my AD domain using `realmd`(`client-software=sssd`) and configured Samba to serve shares.

Upon completing these steps, I have the following problem:

Can't authenticate domain users accessing Samba shares because Samba logs complain that it "Failed to fetch domain SID for MYDOMAIN".
`net getdomainsid` shows SID for local machine, but also reports that "Could not fetch domain SID".

I found a workaround to solve this by either:

1. Leaving the domain then joining again with `realmd` (but this time
   with `client-software=winbind`);
2. Manually setting the SID with `net setdomainsid`

Both approaches will set the domain SID for Samba and allow me to use AD authentication.

So, I would like to know why is it that joining the domain with `client-software=winbind` sets this domain SID, while joining with `client-software=sssd` doesn't. And finally: **is there a way to make `sssd` automatically set this domain SID for Samba while joining the domain?**

Comment: I still haven't figured out why the domain SID isn't set when joining with SSSD, or if that's even possible. But i've found out that I can use "net rpc getsid" to set the domain SID into samba's secrets.tdb, without knowing it beforehand.